# Ayuda con ejercicio en JS creacion y uso de funciones

Tags: javascript, funciones, diccionarios

necesito ayuda con el siguiente ejercicio:

Desarrolla una función que puntúe una mano de cartas, que tenga como parámetro un array de cartas, cada una representada por un diccionario con palo y valor. Al puntuar, las cartas suman su valor excepto si es un as que suma 20.

Declare las cartas el as como 1,cree el array con todas las cartas en el y el codigo, pero el codigo no me da el resultado deseado y no se que estoy haciendo mal

```html
carta1 = {PALO:"c",VALOR:1}
carta2 = {PALO:"d",VALOR:7}
carta3 = {PALO:"p",VALOR:5}

cartas = [carta1,carta2,carta3];

function puntua(mano){
  var mano = 0
for (var i = 0; i < cartas.length; i ++) {
    if (cartas[i].valor === 1) {
        mano = mano + cartas[i].valor + 20;
    } else {
    if (cartas[i].valor != 1) {
        mano = mano + cartas[i].valor;
}
   console.log(puntua(mano))
}
}
}
```

Comment: Cual es el resultado que te da este código? y cual es el resultado deseado? trata de ser mas especifico sobre el problema

Comment: Desarrolla una función que puntúe una mano de cartas, que tenga como parámetro un array de cartas, cada una representada por un diccionario con palo y valor. Al puntuar, las cartas suman su valor excepto si es un as que suma 20.y me tira undefined, yo quiero que me quede bien creada la funcion y que me imprima en consola la suma de las cartas de acuerdo a la condicion declarada,si hay un 1 en las cartas me suma los valores y 20 y si no hubiera un as me suma los valores y me los imprime,pero en algo evidentemente le estoy errando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te faltaban dos cosas:

1. Javascript es case sensitive.  Significa que no es lo mismo mayusculas que minusculas.
2. Solo necesitas una condicion.  Si es uno, sumas 20, todos los otros casos suman su propio valor.

Quedaria algo asi:

```js
carta1 = {PALO:"c",VALOR:1};
carta2 = {PALO:"d",VALOR:7};
carta3 = {PALO:"p",VALOR:5};

cartas = [carta1,carta2,carta3];

function puntua(){
  var mano = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < cartas.length; i ++) {
    if (cartas[i].VALOR == 1) {
        mano = mano + 20;
    } else {    
        mano = mano + cartas[i].VALOR;
    }
   
  }
  console.log(mano);
}

puntua();
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba este código

//primero.

```
puntuar=function(mano){
    var total=0;
     for (i=0; i< mano.length; i++){
     if(i.valor ===1){
            total += 20;
} else{
            total += i.valor;
}} 
return total;
};
```

//segundo.

```
puntuar_doble_rojo=function(mano){
    var total=0;
     for (i=0; i< mano.length; i++){
      var mulitplic=1;
     if(i.palo==='c' || i.palo==='d'){
        mulitplic=2;
}
     if(i.valor ===1){
            total += 20*multiplic;
} else{
            total += i.valor;
}} 
return total;
};
```

//tercero.

```
puntuar_doble_rojo=function(mano1,mano2){
var ganador= 'Ganó el jugador 1';
if (puntuar_doble_rojo(mano2) > puntuar_doble_rojo(mano1)){
ganador= 'Ganó el jugador 2';
}else if (puntuar_doble_rojo(mano2) === puntuar_doble_rojo(mano1)) {
ganador="Fue un empate";
}
console.log(ganador);
}
```